# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNGADBannerView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, admob

**I recently installed admob for react-native.but i m getting an error "RNGADBannerView" was not found in the UIManager".I don't know what that supposed to mean?**

`_can anyone help?_`

```
import {AdMobBanner} from 'react-native-admob';

  export default class Home extends Component{
   render(){
    return <View>
        <Text>helo</Text>
        <AdMobBanner
            adSize="fullBanner"
            adUnitID="my_id"
            onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.error(error)}
        />
    </View>
}
```

**dependencies:**

```
   "react": "16.4.1",
   "react-native": "0.56.0",
   "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
   "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.6.2"
```

Comment: I get the same error. Any ideas what might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you did not link the library to your project.
Using `react-native link` in the root directory of your project should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue `Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent:xxx not found in UIManager`

Issue seems to be the dependent is not linked to your project, hence 2 solutions for this issue (depending on your 'dependency')

1. run `react-native link` in terminal/cmd at your project path.
2. Manual append the dependency in your MainApplication.java as shown below:

```
@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {      

      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for 
      packages.add(new RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage());
      packages.add(new xxxPackage());
    }
```